# How to prevent Firefox log messages in Jenkins job console output?

Tags: .net, firefox, selenium, jenkins

I'm using selenium .NET webdriver with nunit in order to run automated tests.

When I run the tests under Jenkins (This issue doesn't happen when not running under Jenkins), I get a lot of Firefox debugging messages printed to the Jenkins console , for example:

```
1449667715916   addons.manager  DEBUG   Application has been upgraded
1449667715929   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1449667715931   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1449667715934   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm
```

I believe that the reason is that Jenkins catch stdout from the program I execute and the processes created by it (Firefox process is created by the selenium webdriver).

How can I stop those error messages from appearing?

Possible solutions I could think of (I couldn't find a way to preform any of the bellow):

- Prevent Firefox from printing its log messages to its stdout
- Catch Firefox stdout into a file.
- Make Jenkins ignore this process logs.

Comment: have you succeeed? Have the same issue with nunit catching all selenium output from addons.manager DEBUG

Comment: There is a firefox bug about this issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1399441